# How to control fragment onResume?

Tags: android

I have three fragments A、B、C , my process is A to B to C .

I want that when i change to C and call back to B , B can switch to A immediately.

So i set the switch fragment function on `onResume` on B .

But the result is that i always land up on A fragment , because when i change to B the function `onResume` be called

I know i can remove `transaction.addToBackStack(null);` then i can C to A
, but it will cause some bug in my project , so i try to keep it.

Is any function only start when C call back to B ?
Thanks in advance.

Below is my switch function:

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment, null);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

I try to add `onResume` on fragment B , but it will be A to B , and then B go back to A immediately.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //go back to fragment A
    switchFragment(NewHomepage.newInstance());
}
```

Comment: create Boolean and set it to true in B when transaction occurred to C, and in OnResume check if Bool is true then switchFragment

Comment: Thanks man , your remind me the point , it would be worked , but dose it has any possible on life circle , like Activity onRestart that will be call when turn back

Comment: for more accurate result, you can save boolean in SharedPreference inside backpress of C and inside Onresume of B, check if it is true then go to A

Comment: Thanks , one more question , so i still can A to B ? even after the boolean in SharedPreference.

Comment: for that, you can set it back to False inside if condition

Comment: Ok , sounds it will work , i will try it , thanks @DivyeshPatel

Comment: try it and let me know if it is working or not...

Comment: I will , wait for my responding.

Comment: When you navigate from B to C, first do a popbackstack then replace A with C in a transaction. No need to save any state.

Comment: @BladeCoder , yes you mean remove `transaction.addToBackStack(null);` right ? I just afraid of that if i have a lots of fragments , it may cause some overlapping .

Comment: @DivyeshPatel , hey man , i try it and it works , just save it on A for true , get it on B , finally save it again on C for false. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Great..........

Comment: @徐博俊 No that's not it, let me recap. It's better to prepare the back stack when navigating forward, rather than trying to change it when navigating backward. 1 To reach B: A->B with addToBackStack(). 2 To reach C: popBackStack() and immediately after A->C with addToBackStack(). So, when the user sees C and presses back, he'll be back to A.

Comment: Sorry i don't get it , if use some codes for example , `transaction.addToBackStack(null);` on A and C , what code should be on B ? If in my `switchFragment()` method , thanks for your responding.

Answer (score 1):

your fragment transition code should be:

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment, null);
transaction.addToBackStack("fragment_name_tagX");
transaction.commit();
```

}

above, X is your fragment. After you navigate from fragment A to C using above function, your stack will have every fragment with name 'fragment_name_tag' that you assign.

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    int count = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count != 0) {
        fm.popBackStack ("fragment_name_tagB",FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

So when you now press back button from fragment C, it will go on fragment A.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but i have a lots of fragments , i have another function to controll popBackStack , i'm afraid of it will confuse with my project.

Comment: @徐博俊 so on what event do you want to navigate from fragment C to A ?

Comment: B input some value and take the user to C , when user click back then take it to A , i just get some solution for others , thanks for your help man.